# Stability analysis of coupled ordinary differential equations

Tags: stability

Given a forward-in-time approximation I have the coupled equations:
$$
\frac{T^{(n+1)} - T^{(n)}}{\Delta t} = x T^{(n)} - y h^{(n)} \\
\frac{h^{(n+1)} - h^{(n)}}{\Delta t} = -z h^{(n)} - \alpha T^{(n)}
$$
where $x, y, z$ and $\alpha$ are constants, I see from my simulation that the solution is damping. But how can I use Von Neumann analysis to find the amplication factor $A$?

Comment: can someone explain von neumann stability analysis for system of equation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rewrite your finite difference method into the form

\begin{align}\left[\begin{matrix} T^{t+1} \\ h^{t+1}\end{matrix} \right]=\left[\begin{matrix}A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{matrix} \right] \left[\begin{matrix} T^n\\h^n\end{matrix} \right] = \left[\begin{matrix}A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{matrix} \right]^n\left[\begin{matrix} T^0\\h^0\end{matrix} \right]
\end{align}

Rewritten this way, you will find that the matrix $A$ becomes $$A=I+\Delta tJ,$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ is the jacobian of the RHS of your original system.  $A$ can be thought of as the *amplification matrix*, whose eigenvalues determine the stability of the numerical system.  To ensure absolute stability, you need to find a region in the complex vector space such that the spectral radius $\rho(A)<1$ (i.e. the dominant eigenvalue is less than one).

Of course, since this is a *system of ODE's*, you need to be extra careful.  [Stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability) and [consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations#Consistency_and_order) may not be enough to ensure an accurate solution.  You'll also need to check for [Stiffness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation).

Comment: good answer. This may also explain the damping via *A-stability*. However, this is different from *von Neumann* stability analysis.

Comment: @jan:  indeed this is not von neumann analysis, for the equation itself isn't a PDE, but an ODE.

Comment: Ouch, sounds like I need to learn me some more numerical methods before I attempt this!  We've not covered stiffness or eigenvalues.